# Puppet - how can I add host entry dynamically reading from linux $hostname

Tags: amazon-ec2, puppet, provisioning

I am using puppet for provisioning to AWS cloud. I am a newbie to this.
My requirement is to add entry into /etc/hosts file of amazon ec2 instance. However at the time of writing puppet, I do not know the actual hostname.

How can I use $HOSTNAME variable in .pp file?

Something like this -

```
host { '$HOSTNAME':
  ip => 'echo $HOSTNAME | tr "-" "." | sed 's/ip.//'',
  host_aliases => 'mywebsite',
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Something like this :

```
host { $fqdn : 
  ip => $ipaddress,
  host_aliases => 'mywebsite',
}
```

`$fqdn` provides fully qualified domain name and `$ipaddress` provides IP address for the machine. These variables are available if you have `facter` installed in your system. `facter` is available at the puppetlab repo. You can install it the same way you installed `puppet` in your system.

As in the comment, you can also use `$hostname` to get the short-hostname in place of `$fqdn`.

Comment: fqdn is good but I would add $hostname to host_aliases to get the short name also.  Can put multiple aliases in by specifying an array.

Comment: Puppet is not functional without facter, so it can safely assumed that it is already installed.

Comment: if you need both fqdn and hostname you can do `host_aliases => $::hostname`

Answer (score 0):

Since I wanted the hosts file to be updated before startup script's start gets executed, I did this and it worked for me.

Added this in /etc/init.d/

```
setup_hostname() {
  IPADDR=`echo $HOSTNAME | tr "-" "." | sed 's/ip.//'`
  echo "${IPADDR} ${HOSTNAME}" >> /etc/hosts
}
```

Called setup_hostname from start

```
case "$1" in
  start)
  clean
  setup_hostname
  start
;;
```